# Issue With a String Not Able To Concatenate

Tags: c#

The desktop client we use with our phone system has an API which allows us to capture the telephone number of the phone as it rings.
In order to use the API you reference a DLL and specify.

```
using TelephonyProxy;

public class program
{

    private static Commander commander;
    private static Listener listener;

    static void Main()
    {
        commander = new Commander();
        listener =  new Listener();
        SubscribeToListener();
    }

    private static void SubcribeToListener()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Subscribe To Listener");
        listener.Connect += OnConnect;
        listener.Disconnect += OnDisconnect;
        listener.Offering += OnOffering;
        listener.Ringback += OnRingback;
    }


    private static void OnOffering(string name, string number)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(number + “abc”);
    }
}
```

The issue is the OnOffering is called correctly and the telephone number is in the number variable. However the debug only shows the number and not the “abc”. In testing it seems you can concatenate anything in front of number but anything after is ignored.

Have you any idea why that might be?

Thanks for any input you can give this.

Comment: Does number end with \0 ? Anything after \0 won't be rendered. Example: `var test = "a\0b"; Debug.WriteLine(test); // only prints a`

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine(number + “abc”);` those are not speech marks that the debugger will recognise

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I was wondering about those, but the application won't compile if they're present so I suspect that isn't his problem.

Comment: have you tried other string concatenation methods? like `Debug.WriteLine($"{number}abc");`

Comment: @john: I have tested it in `Visual Studio`, and the `Output` window does not show anything after `\0`. Add an answer because it is interesting issue.

Comment: @apocalypse As per Goos' answer, try string interpolation (if on C# 6.0 or higher) and see if that works?

Comment: @silkfire: string interpolation does not help. `\0` still exists in result string. It's the `output` window issue.

Comment: @apocalypse Why do you think that the string ends with `\0`? Btw, why are you replying for viperdudeuk?

Comment: @silkfire I believe they're just trying the answers out to see what's plausible

Comment: @silkfire It seems to be a logical conclusion. StringBuilder, String.Concat, and C# 6 string interpolation will all achieve the same thing as string+string. If it isn't showing up using string+string, then it won't with any of the others. A string containing `\0` is a plausible reason as to why the remainder of the string would not be printed to Output window. Can you think of any others?

Comment: @john Probably there's a black hole right after the phone number that swallows everything that comes after :)

Comment: @silkfire That's possible, too!

Comment: @silkfire apparently it seems to have also swallowed OP as well...

Comment: OP - did my answer solve your issue? If so, can you accept my answer, please?

Answer (score 2):

ASCII character 0 (represented in the debugger as \0) is sometimes used to terminate strings. If you're dealing with something like a COM device, etc., this may be the case.

For example:

```
Debug.WriteLine("a\0b");
```

will only output "a". ASCII character 0 is not printed, nor are any of the subsequent characters. Naturally, appending something to such a string will mean that anything after \0 in the original string, nothing will appear.

If you're dealing with COM, look at the string in the debugger and see if \0 is on the end.

You could remove it using replace:

```
Debug.WriteLine(number.Replace("\0", "") + "abc");
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it.